# On git status I'm getting the subfolders of the main folder i want to add

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I want to add the main folder "my_project" to my bitbucket account, but on git status I'm getting the subfolders of the folder "my_project". So when I type in `git add` my_project im getting an error. How can I get to be displayed in the cmd the main folder "my_project" and not the subfolders of it? Can anyone help me?

I have tried with git reset and other stuff but it didn't help me.

Here I'm getting the subfolders of my_project and I don't have only my_project folder that contains the subfolders.
[image]

Here is the folder my_project on C disc

[image]

Comment: AFAIK if you add the parent directory, then all subdirectories will also be added, unless you excluded them through a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Why is your entire user directory a Git repository? (That's not C drive, that's `C:/Users/{your_user}/`) I assume you want that `.git` folder to be inside `my_project` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `.git` directory from your home directory.

```
rm -rf .git/
```

Then go to your project directory

```
cd my_project/
```

Now initialize git repository

```
git init
git status
```